# 'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command (tried everything, still not working)

Tags: maven, terminal, environment-variables

Sorry I bother you, but this is my last option. I've read lot of an articles also from here Stackoverflow, and tried all things in those articles, but still not working. I really have a headache of this maven-enviromental-case, it is exploding my head very soon.

I have installed Maven to `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4`

I have put it to the System Enviroment variables like this:

```
Variable          Value
MAVEN_HOME        C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4
```

Included `MAVEN_HOME` to System Enviroment Variables path like this: `%MAVEN_HOME%\bin`. Also tried to include location itself to the path like this `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4`
.

Also tried to add those all in User variables. Restarted computer, tried to run CMD as Administrator, any of these working. If I echo `%MAVEN_HOME%` I get `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4`. In IntelliJ IDEA I see the MAVEN_HOME variable in terminal variables.

Added it to System like this:
[image]

And to the PATH like this:
[image]

Echoing `%PATH%` in CMD:
[image]

Maven install directory:
[image]

Comment: Did you add %MAVEN_HOME%\bin to the PATH? The environment variable MAVEN_HOME by itself doesn't do anything or mean anything.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes I've done that.

Comment: Please show how you added it to the path. Did you reopen your command prompt after adding it?

Comment: So can you verify this by including the output of `echo %PATH%` to your question? Modifying the Windows path is an extremely common FAQ; did you review existing questions?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel edited the question, and there is screenshots now. I restarted CMD and Windows also.

Comment: The last screenshot shows you set the path wrong, otherwise it would have shown `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4\bin` (and not `C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.8.4` like it does now).

Comment: @tripleee I reviewed existing questions and tried those answers with no solution. That is why I send new. I edited question, these is now results of echoing the path in CMD.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel still not working.

Comment: Please show the directory where you have extracted the installation archive

Comment: @khmarbaise added screenshot to the question.

Comment: You forgot the `\bin`

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Ah something I expected. You have downloaded the github archive but not installation archive https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi  (-bin.zip file!). Remove the whole directory first (delete it!)...download the zip archive from the download side and unpack it into the same location...

Comment: @khmarbaise That was the reason, enviroments was ok. Lot of thanks!! Please write an answer of that so I can accept it as a solution. Awesome!

Comment: Just a small supplemental. The defined `MAVEN_HOME` is simply not needed. Put the whole path into `PATH` that's all you need...after changing close the dos box and reopen it afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah something I expected. You have downloaded the github archive but not installation archive https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi (-bin.zip file!). Remove the whole directory first (delete it!)...download the zip archive from the download side and unpack it into the same location...